# looping for a time series object

Tags: r, variables, zoo, rollapply

I know this may look like a long post, but it is a simple issue related to looping in zoo. Please read on:

```
# required libraries:

library(vars)
library(zoo)

# create time series
model <- zoo(x = cbind(rnorm(10),rnorm(10)*2, rnorm(10)*0.2), order.by = as.Date(1:10))

> model
1970-01-02 -0.32247034 -2.8667554 -0.08572468
1970-01-03 -1.33880074 -2.1103700 -0.13123590
1970-01-04  0.68815603 -1.4662238  0.19187887
1970-01-05  0.07128065  0.4218145  0.31121053
1970-01-06  2.18975236 -1.9978415 -0.20815929
1970-01-07 -1.15770760  2.1557006  0.18611448
1970-01-08  1.18168806 -2.3979488 -0.01508919
1970-01-09 -0.52736836  0.4332741 -0.39343907
1970-01-10 -1.45662801  0.2861741 -0.15118073
1970-01-11  0.57296737 -2.1315002  0.09222983
```

I want to create a zoo time series object that contains coefficients from a VAR equation for each date, using only data available at that time. I only want coefficients for variable "X". Specifically, I want to loop these functions:

```
> coef(VAR(model[1:5]))$x[,1]
       x.l1        y.l1        z.l1       const 
   6.366133   51.897180 -273.933190  -28.856147 

> coef(VAR(model[1:6]))$x[,1]
      x.l1       y.l1       z.l1      const 
-0.1726954  0.5972525 -1.9151799 -0.4963311 

> coef(VAR(model[1:7]))$x[,1]
      x.l1       y.l1       z.l1      const 
-0.3567360 -0.1969814  1.0163298 -0.1171288 

> coef(VAR(model[1:8]))$x[,1]
       x.l1        y.l1        z.l1       const 
-0.54919705 -0.09963062  0.47934378 -0.20755763 

> coef(VAR(model[1:9]))$x[,1]
      x.l1       y.l1       z.l1      const 
-0.4623637 -0.2161147  1.5129717 -0.3003821 

> coef(VAR(model[1:10]))$x[,1]
      x.l1       y.l1       z.l1      const 
-0.5041168 -0.2164998  1.5813547 -0.2684235
```

and put them in an appropriately indexed zoo object, such as:

```
                  x.l1       y.l2        z.l1       const
1970-01-02          NA         NA           NA         NA
1970-01-03          NA         NA           NA         NA
1970-01-04          NA         NA           NA         NA
1970-01-05          NA         NA           NA         NA
1970-01-06    6.366133    51.897180 -273.933190  -28.856147 
1970-01-07  -0.1726954    0.5972525  -1.9151799  -0.4963311 
1970-01-08  -0.3567360   -0.1969814   1.0163298  -0.1171288 
1970-01-09 -0.54919705  -0.09963062  0.47934378 -0.20755763 
1970-01-10  -0.4623637   -0.2161147   1.5129717  -0.3003821 
1970-01-11  -0.5041168   -0.2164998   1.5813547  -0.2684235
```

I have tried this, but it does not create a time-series object (only the result from the final iteration):

```
for (i in 2:(nrow(model)-3))
{
        b <- coef(VAR(model[1:(ncol(model)+i)]))$x[,1]
}
```

I also tried rollapply, which creates a zoo object, but the numbers look odd:

```
rollapply(model, width = seq_along(model[,1])[5:10], 
                 function(x) coef(VAR(x))$x[,1],
                 by.column = FALSE, align = "right")

                 x.l1       y.l1       z.l1      const
1970-01-08  0.8259929 -0.4151388  1.1475067 -0.1905136
1970-01-09 -1.5161721  0.6774460 -7.0410817  1.0445796
1970-01-10 -0.1054592 -0.1699834  0.3326742 -0.2718832
1970-01-11 -0.2773018 -0.1760636  0.6023782 -0.1737401
```

Please help. I've spent two days on this! Many thanks

Comment: `i<-list(1:5,1:6,1:7,1:8,1:9,1:10); lapply(i,function(j)coef(VAR(model[j]))$x[,1])` ?

Comment: Not bad, but it does not include time indexation. Also, I need a more generalised solution if possible (instead of typing 1:5, 1:6 etc which depends on the specific data series).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the package VAR. 
I get a NULL when i run 
    coef(VAR(model[1:5]))$x[,1] 
    #This is my sessionInfo()

```
# R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
# Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
# 
# other attached packages:
# [1] vars_1.5-2    zoo_1.7-11 

library(vars)
library(zoo)

# create time series
model <- zoo(x = cbind(rnorm(10),rnorm(10)*2, rnorm(10)*0.2), order.by = as.Date(1:10))

coef(VAR(model[1:10]))$x[,1]
# NULL

#This is what i use instead
coef(VAR(model[1:5]))[, 1]

# assign your starting point
starting.point <- 5

# run everything else without changing anything
coefs <- lapply(starting.point:dim(model)[1], function(x){
  coef(VAR(model[1:x]))[[1]][, 1]
})

coefs <- do.call(rbind, coefs)
coefs <- rbind(matrix(NA, starting.point-1, dim(model)[2]+1), coefs)

model2 <- zoo(x = coefs, order.by = as.Date(1:10))
model2
```

Comment: Even though it's longer than the one below, it does the job on the sample data! Any idea how to generalise it for any number of variables and dates? Thanks

Comment: Replace `model2` with
`model2 <- zoo(x = coefs, order.by = index(model))`
Then the only thing you need to define each time you run it is the `starting.point <- 5`

Answer (score 2):

Try `rollapplyr` with the indicated `Coef` function.  Note that we added column names to `model`.

```
library(vars)
library(zoo)

# input
set.seed(123)
n <- 10
model <- zoo(cbind(x = rnorm(n), rnorm(n)*2, rnorm(n)*0.2), order.by = as.Date(1:n))
colnames(model) <- c("x", "y", "z")

Coef <- function(m) coef(VAR(m))[[1]][, 1]
rollapplyr(model, pmax(ncol(model)+2, 1:nrow(model)), Coef, by.column = FALSE)
```

giving:

```
                  x.l1        y.l1      z.l1      const
1970-01-06  0.35854742  0.34666660 13.353457  1.9739107
1970-01-07 -0.09281548 -0.31745594  7.959080  2.0291699
1970-01-08  0.28089541 -0.05197486  5.983763  1.6170001
1970-01-09 -0.21759494 -0.42397646 -4.403415  0.3414522
1970-01-10 -0.01879181 -0.09968207 -3.504636 -0.1123601
1970-01-11  0.18226642 -0.14726950 -2.821511 -0.1400125
```

See `?rollapply` for more info.

Please use `set.seed` for reproducibility when posting examples that use random numbers.

Comment: that's a beautiful solution, thanks. Any idea how to generalise it for any number of variables and dates?